# Owl-Carousel not working with Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, owl-carousel

Owl Carousel isn't working with my rails install.  It's not showing up on my test page and this error appears in the Chrome developers console:

[image: Chrome console error highlighting call to .owlCarousel()]

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

I've followed the directions on https://github.com/acrogenesis/owlcarousel-rails

and [even installed this fix since Rails turbolinks apparently messes with DOM triggers](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks).

Here is the relevant code in rails:

```
**GemFile**
gem 'owlcarousel-rails'

**app/assets/application.js**
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap
//= require owl.carousel
//= require_tree .

**app/assets/stylesheets/application.css**
*= require_tree .
*= require_self 
*= require owl.carousel
*= require owl.theme

**home.html.erb**
<body>
...
<div class="owl-carousel" col-lg-12">
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
</div>
...
</body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    autoPlay: 3000,
    item: 3
 });
});
</script>
```

As of right now, this is what the area looks like (should have content in the white area):
[image: Screenshot of page showing only page title]

Comment: `jquery.turbolinks` says to place `require turbolinks` after all of your other `require` statements.  Have you tried doing so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check your javascript files as it seems you have an extra initializer somewhere, as evidenced by the Chrome Dev Tools error:

`$('#owl-carousel').owlCarousel();`

which is quite different from your

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  autoPlay: 3000,
  item: 3
});
```

The error is ocurring because `$('#owl-carousel')` returns a null object, since you have no object with id='owl-carousel'

Comment: Changed the initializer line to call the class .owl-carousel and still gives the same error in javascript console: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`.

Comment: This might be a long shot, but MAYBE are you missing the line `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>` in your app/views/layouts/application.html.erb file?

Answer (score 5):

Just in case anyone else having this issue comes across this page, I built out a quick repo that demonstrates a working version of the `owlcarousel-rails` gem embedded in a bootstrap grid.  I also explain the changes I made in the `README`.

I know sometimes one needs to see all the working parts together to figure out exactly where one is going wrong.

REPO HERE: https://github.com/EliCash82/carousel-optimization

Take a look in `app/assets/javascripts`, `app/assets/stylesheets`, and most importantly `app/views/static_pages/carousel_in_grid.html.erb`

Hope this helps someone out :)

Comment: thanks this $(document).ready(function() {}) before $("#owl-carousel").owlCarousel({}) solved my problem in owl carousel

Answer (score 2):

I think you have an extra quotation mark in

```
<div class="owl-carousel" col-lg-12">
```

and it's not rendering correctly. change to

```
<div class="owl-carousel col-lg-12">
```

Comment: You forgot to add what it's supposed to change to ;)

Answer (score 0):

I used owl carousel with one of my rails projects. You needn't install the gem. Try removing the line from your Gemfile. Make sure you have the correct path to owl.carousel.js in application.js and owl.*.css in application.css. And restart the server.

Also, I would recommend moving any external js (owl.carousel.js) and css (owl.carousel.css, owl.theme.css) to vendor/assets/.

Comment: changed this all around, added the files: `owl.carousel.js ~> vendor/assets/javascripts` and `owl.carousel.css` and `owl.theme.css ~> vendor/assets/stylesheets`.  Removed gem as well.  Rebooted, checked source code in header and see the references to the files, but still have the same results.